# Keep a ration between body font-size and Headings

Tags: css

Is it possible to achieve this in CSS:

I'd like to keep a Typographic hierarchy in my document. I'd like to change dynamically the size (keeping a ratio) of my Headings depending on the font-size of my body in px.

Let's say I want my Headings and body size to keep in sync between each other and change depending on body's font-size in px.
If the size of body's font-size increases/decreases the Headings h1,h2,h3 also follow and keep a ratio.

is this something doable in CSS alone?

Comment: yes, if you set a font size in  body, the rest should follow. if you did reset font-size to your headings , then use rem units to resize them  from the body's font-size. https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/ (a link found among others )

Comment: thank you! I'll take a look at that article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question asks how to make sure all font sizes in a document change proportional to the size set in the body element.

If you set a definite size in the body and thereafter use the em unit to size your fonts you will find that everything changes proportionally.

BUT be aware that the em unit is itself a relative unit. That is actually probably what you want, but just make sure. Consider this example. The div which is a child of the h1 element has a font size proportional to the h1's font size which is itself proportional to its parent's (body element) font size. The div which is not a child of h1, only of the body element has a font size proportional only to the body's font size. See snippet below.

There is another unit, rem (root em) which is set in the html e`leme`nt of the document. Most browsers set the basic font size o 16px there and thus that is what 1rem is. You can change that and set for example our body font size in terms of rem. The main reason for doing that would be to acknowledge that the user can change the basic setting in their browser, perhaps they hope that all text will then become automatically bigger, so it is considerate to set your body font size in terms of rem.

To make the arithmetic of this easier, set

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

Your rem will then be 10px (or a proportion of whatever the user has set). Then to get your body font-size to say 24px (for most users or proportional to the users browser setting) by

```
body {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}
```

From there on in use em or rem depending on what suits your case at particular points in the document and everything will be proportional, and as a bonus, give the user better accessibility.
Here's a snippet to illustrate:

```css
html :
  font-size: 62.5%;/* 10px on most browsers */
}

body {
  font-size: 2.4rem;/* 24px; */
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;/* 48px; */
}

div {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
This is inside the body only
<h1>This is h1 inside body and with font-size 2em
  <div>This is div inside h1 and with font-size 1.5em</div>
  </h1>
  
  <h1>This is h1 inside body and with font-size 2em
  </h1>
  <div>This is div outside h1 and with font-size 1.5em</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: thank you very much for this extensive explanation. Now I see why it wasn't working properly using pixels. I'll try and implement your suggestions. Thank you again for your time.